# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).datepicker is not a function, WP Theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i have an error with a custom WordPress theme of a client website.

This is the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).datepicker is not a function
```

The code with the error is this one:

```
jQuery.browser.mozilla && jQuery('#zn_form input:radio').each(function () {

            this.checked = this.defaultChecked;

        }); 
        /* Start datepicker*/
        jQuery(".zn_date_picker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy"
        });

        jQuery('.zn_time_picker').timepicker({
            'timeFormat': 'H:i'
        });
```

I tried to modify datepicker with .datetimepicker but i have the same error.

Is someone can help me to resolve this please, i'm very bad at JS :-(

Thank you for your time.

Comment: did you enqueue datepicker js script in wp???

Comment: Make sure you had included datepicker js before your above code.

Comment: you forgot to include datepicker.js file, please double check you have included it

Comment: Did you include jQuery UI on your page?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, datepicker is a jquery UI plug in, so you would have to download and link JQUERY UI